# How to edit product image size?

Tags: magento-1.9

On my site(it is live now), my product image size i specified was 255px x 344px. But the customers uploaded images of size 1024px x 683px. So the images look very bad now. how can i re size the images without affecting its clarity?

Answer (score 3):

Magento `keepAspectRatio(bool), keepFrame(bool) and resize(width,height)` will solve image sizing related problems for any image.

In your theme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml find the related code to show images and add this code.

```
->keepFrame(true)->resize(255,344)->keepAspectRatio(true);
```

Hope it solves your problem.